# Unable to write files on Windows

Tags: c, windows, io, save

I am trying to save some files using C, with this code:

```
sprintf(playerinput,"%s",end);
sprintf(fileloc,"%s/.notend",getenv("HOME"));
playerdata = fopen(fileloc, "w+"); /*create the new file*/
if (!playerdata)
{
printf("\n\t\t\tCould not save settings file.");    
return;
} else {
fputs(playerinput,playerdata); 
fclose(playerdata); 
}
```

It should set playerinput to the end variable, which works on Linux, then set the file location to the homearea/.notend, then make or edit the file, and put it out. In Linux (gcc), this works fine. The same code, however, on Windows (i586-mingw32msvc-gcc, does not work. Am I doing something wrong, or is another header file needed? Currently I have:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_NOTES 200
#define MAX_NAMES_TEXT 200
#define MAX_NOTES_TEXT 2000
```

as my headers and defines. If you need more information, just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment variable `HOME` is not a default environment variable on Windows so:

```
getenv("HOME");
```

will return `NULL`. You need to use a different function to obtain a user's home directory on Windows, [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will provide this:

```
char path[MAX_PATH + 1] = "";

if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(0, 
                              CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA,
                              0,
                              SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT,
                              path)))
{
    std::cout << path << "\n";
}
```

This output:

> C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Local Settings\Application Data

on my machine.

Comment: Ah, that is probably the issue. It gets nothing from that, so is trying to save .notend in no directory. What should I use instead of HOME?

Comment: @user1150512: Please do accept this answer if this solved your case.

Answer (score 1):

To which location are you trying to write your file? Does the application have the right permissions to write to that location?

EDIT: Looking at the path style you just defined `C://Documents and Settings//...`, you should try it with `C:\\\\Documents and Settings\\...`. Note that there's double backslash for each slash in the path. I'm not sure if fopen() would convert `/` to `\`, so it's worth a try.

If you're sure that this would be running on Windows Vista and above you can get this path using `getenv("HOMEPATH")`. I would suggest a macro definition like:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#    define HOME_ENV "HOMEPATH"
#else
#    define HOME_ENV "HOME"
#endif
```

followed by:
`getenv(HOME_ENV)` to get the home directory for the user.

Comment: I am trying to save the files to the users home directory (I think on windows this would be C://Documents and Settings/user). As the same user is running the program as the file directory, I believe the permissions would be right.

Comment: If he's creating a "dot file" the customary place to save it would be in APPDATA (or, better, a directory under it). And, you have to concatenate HOMEDRIVE (or HOMESHARE) to HOMEPATH to get a complete path, your solution would break if it's not on the C drive - USERPROFILE is the appropriate variable for the whole directory name.