# File output on a target computer

Tags: visual-c++, file-io

I have a windows form application that uses the following

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("foo.csv");
myfile << "whatever";
myfile.close()
```

The file outputs just fine onto my computer into the same directory the application is in (release folder automatically after compiling). However, I can't get the file to output if I move the application to another place on my computer, or onto a target computer when it is distributed using a windows setup file. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Check if `my_file.is_open()`. It may be there is a permission issue in the directory in which the process is being run.

Comment: When I do that; the file is open in the default directory, but when I move the application to another location, the file is not open. How do I change the permission issue?

Comment: you may not be able to. You could attempt to create the file in a temp or user specific directory?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706084/unable-to-write-files-on-windows/9706240#9706240 for using `SHGetFolderPath`.

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine on any computer.

Two likely causes:

1) An error is occurring that prevents the file from being written, or

2) The file isn't being written where you expect it to be

Definitely check for errors.  For example:

```
std::ofstream outFile("foo.csv");
if (!outFile)
{
   // Open failed - take error handling action.
}
```

ADDENDUM: this prints the error message:

```
std::ofstream outFile("foo.csv");
if (!outFile)
{
   // Open failed - take error handling action.
   cout << "error reading file foo.csv" << " error: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
}
```

Comment: I searched and the file wasn't anywhere else on the computer. So it must be an error that is occurring. How do I see what the error is/ how do I handle it?

Comment: You see *if* an error has occurred by checking for a null stream ("if !outFile").  I've updated the code snippet with strerror(), which prints the exact error.  If the error is "permissions", then you need to 1) allow write access for your directory, or 2) write to a different directory ;)

Comment: Q: Where are you trying to write this file?  Under c:\Program files?  That won't work for Vista or Win7, unless you "Run as Administrator":  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/permission-denied-accessing-program-files/9ea4c7cd-cd53-4c50-9994-0f01a337df80   http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-do-i-get-round-windows-7s-file-permissions/d048994f-7a95-469d-b2f5-b334b236a5e3

Comment: Excellent! that worked! Is there any way that I can do that so the user doesn't have to click "run as admin"? or will I have to set the file to install in a different directory?